# Enter a Tuple into a Table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Following Problem. I'm trying to Insert some Data into an mySql Database. The connection to the server works and he isn't responding any PHP-Error or MySql Error. So it looks like it works, but it will not enter anything into the Database:

```
 //print "I can see this Print"; //works until here!!!
    $query = ("INSERT INTO Brands 
    (BName,BAddress,BPostalCode,BCity,BCountry,BContactPerson) 
    VALUES ('$BName','$BAddress','$BPostalCode','$BCity','$BCountry',
    '$BContactPerson'");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Hope anybody can Help!!! 
Thank you

Comment: Do you use transactions? BTW use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing one paranthesis.

Try with that syntax:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Brands 
          (BName, BAddress, BPostalCode, BCity, BCountry, BContactPerson) 
          VALUES 
          ('".$BName."', '".$BAddress."', '".$BPostalCode."', '".$BCity."', '".$BCountry."', '".$BContactPerson."')";
```